# How to disable tracking position in Aframe

Tags: three.js, aframe, oculus

Try to disable tracking position on occulus, don't find any doc on it.

I've search postionnal tracking, but nothing in aframe

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tracking&type=

Maybe with THREE.JS?

Comment: Removed tags from title; noise reduction; layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using any built-in A-Frame components, as of 0.8.0. What you're probably looking for is the `look-controls` component, which handles mouse and headset rotation/position.

[look-controls documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/look-controls.html)

There is an option to disable HMDs entirely, but none for just turning off position. You could request the feature or create your own version of `look-controls`, but I would be hesitant about that — it will make VR experiences much less comfortable for HMD users.

Comment: I've tried to disable hmd, but no effect. It's look like [this bug](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3459). [Remove VREffect / VRControls in favor of the new WebGLRenderer API](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/3152) has a big impact.

Comment: Hm bug or no, it wasn't intended to disable positional tracking. It would (if it worked) disable rotation too. So I think the feature you want currently doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack :)

This code is not tested, but here the idea :)

```
// html
<entity class="Camera__parent">
  <camera class="Camera" />
</entity>

//js
const cameraParent = document.querySelector('.Camera__parent')
const camera = document.querySelector('.Camera')

function update() {
  requestAnimationFrame(update)
  cameraParent.object3D.position.y = -camera.object3D.position.y
}

if(AFRAME.utils.device.checkHasPositionalTracking())
  update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree with Don that limiting positional tracking on any 6 DOF device makes for a bad user experience as certain types of movement are expected; but there is always room for experimentation!

Though not built into A-Frame you could look at creating a component to reset position (and only position - if you mess with the matrix transforms they will overwrite all transforms - scale, transform, rotation - in the THREEjs layer underneath).

Looks like there is an example below that might work. You could also look here for a start [glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-parent-constraint](http://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-parent-constraint) though I must admit I had difficulties updating individual transforms at the end.